# A multi-queue architecture using systemd

Tags: systemd

I have a service that do some long processing on files, it needs a particular resource to do the processing that can only be used once at a time.

The user may need that resource during the day, but not at night. During the day, he can use it for doing the same processing or other doing other things.

The user also have a list of files to be processed at night, he can put add these to a queue folder at any time and they will be processed at night.

In order to achieve this, I have:

*Folder structure:*

```
.
├── IN  # user add files to be processed here
├── QUEUE  # files that will be processed
├── PROCESSING  # queue of size <= 1, contains the file being processed
├── OUT  # when files have been processed, the service move them here
```

*Services:*

```
# sync QUEUE with IN (possibly with --delete or not)
sync.service  
# pick the oldest file from QUEUE and copy it to PROCESSING
pick_one.service  
# process the file in PROCESSING, 
# remove it from IN, QUEUE and PROCESSING when completed and move it to OUT
processing.service
```

*Path units:*

```
sync.path   # should trigger on each modification of IN folder
pick_one.path  # should trigger while QUEUE is not empty and only when PROCESSING is
processing.path  # should trigger whem a file is present in PROCESSING
```

*Timer:*

```
start.timer  # trigger sync.path and pick_one.path using a target ommitted here 
stop.timer  # stop sync.path and pick_one.path using a target ommitted here
```

With this system I want the user would be able to put files to process anytime in `IN`, those files would be processed at night. I have the flexibility of choosing if the user can delete files from `IN` and those files would still be processed or not by using the intermediary `QUEUE` and `sync.service`. `processing.path` continue to run during the day so user can process a file he wants to just by putting it in the `PROCESSING` folder.

The thing is that I cannot find the necessary options in the path unit in order to achieve it. It seems that I can't monitor `IN` for modifications or avoid a batch processing of the content of `QUEUE` with a `while QUEUE not empty` loop waiting for `tune.service` to finish (I guess using a `while PROCESSING not empty`). Am I right?

I like the flexibility of that solution, however I might over complicate it and this might not be realisable with pure systemd like I was trying to do.

Does anyone has a better approach to propose than mine?

Thank you

PS: I can post the content of the unit file if you think it is needed, but I tried to make that post as clear as possible without making it too long.

Comment: Instead of the while loop I would use `inotify` to wait efficiently. I won't use the `path` unit though, except maybe for monitoring `PROCESSING`. In the end, it seems to me that relying on `inotify` in the services instead of systemd.path unit is a better alternative.

Answer (score 3):

I think my first remark here is that I'm seeing you use the terms "copy", "sync" (rsync?) and "--delete" (which further makes me think of rsync), while a proper implementation of a queueing service as you describe should worry about the *atomicity* of the files in each queue.

Assuming you have `IN`, `PROCESSING` and `OUT`, managed by your queue processor, you should use atomic system calls such as [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) and [link(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html) (as in "hardlink") to move or duplicate/copy files between multiple queues.

Another issue is with ingestion of files into your queues. You should have the processes writing processes to the queue only put them in the `IN` directory once they're complete, otherwise you run into the issue with atomicity again (if your queue processor is quicker than the process writing the item, it might just find an empty file before the writer has time to fill it with contents.)

The way to solve that is to have an additional directory, say `TMP`, that is not watched by the queueing system, but used by writers to file new items. The writers would create a new file there, populate it with contents, close the file, and only then use [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) or [link(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html) to move them to the `IN` queue and have them available for the queue processor to pick them up.

I didn't really understand what you wanted with the two separate queues `IN` and `QUEUE`, perhaps this was an idea similar to `TMP` I mentioned, however you talked about a background service moving items between these two, while the point of `TMP` is to be synchronized with the process filing an item to the queue, since that's the atomicity issue you have to solve there.

Regarding a systemd service, it seems to me you can make do with a single systemd service running the whole queue, picking up items in `IN`, temporarily moving them to `PROCESSING` and finally dumping them in `OUT` when done.

Depending on how long the processing your queue jobs are and how quickly you need them started (if you care about latency at all), perhaps starting with something really simple such as polling the `IN` directory in regular intervals while the queue processor is idle might be enough. You could poll it every 5s or even 60s or so while the queue is empty, and then start polling again as soon as a job is finished (so if you have a busy queue, jobs will run back-to-back.)

Yes, using something like [inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) can make this more efficient, but really only when the queue is empty, since when it's full you'll run your jobs back-to-back, as right after you finish a job you'll rescan the directory to pick a new job from there (and inotify can't really help you with that.)

If you decide to go with inotify, you can either implement that in your daemon itself, which could stay up, but when the queue is empty it would register an inotify on it and go to sleep, to be woken up once an item is placed on the queue. Or you could leverage a [systemd path unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html), in which case you could keep the service down while the queue is empty and have systemd start it only once there are items to process.

Using inotify either way has potential race conditions. What if you scanned the queue and found it empty, so you decided to go to sleep. But right before you do, a new job is added to the queue, triggering a notification. But the notification arrives before you had decided to go to sleep, so since you were still on the mode that's traversing the queue, you decided the notification was not needed, so ignored it? That ends up with your process sleeping while there's an item on the queue, and it won't really get woken up until (or if ever) another item is queued.

So, think twice about introducing inotify into the picture (be it directly or through systemd path units), since it's quite a bit of extra complexity and you don't necessarily have to deal with it if you can poll at reasonably large intervals.

I hope these pointers are useful!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an outline of how I would solve this problem. I would create one service program, that is started using path activation in the IN directory and also by a timer (at night). This service program has the task to look for files in the IN directory and move all found files to the QUEUE directory, *and* (if the day of time is appropriate) start processing of the files, one by one. The program could alternate between these two tasks, or they could be done in parallel in separate threads.

The key principle of this system should be that the program does all the work that is available and the exits, to be started by systemd when there is more work (new files). The role of systemd is just to function as an alarm clock, waking up the service when there is some work to be done. The service itself should check how much work there is to be done, and recheck before exiting.

I need to mention one complication with this file based system: it is possible, and indeed even likely, that a file is still open for writing when it is copied into the IN directory. The path unit triggers when the file appears in the directory, but the copy process has not finished writing to it. This can lead to data corruption. The file should be moved or linked atomically to the IN directory, or some other mechanism should be used to poll until the copy process has closed the file.